# Office JavaScript API - number of pages

Tags: add-in, office-js, word-addins

How do I get in  office.js the page number for a whole document? I want to insert the page number using a Word add-in.

Comment: Please read the guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Currently this scenario isn't supported by WordApi. There is however a [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/12850587-any-way-to-get-current-active-page-for-word-docume) request for this that you could stick some votes on.